# Microsoft Access VBA using a variable field in a calculation

Tags: vba, loops, field

I have a form that has a field with Inventory On Hand called QOH. I have 30 fields, each one contains a daily requirement and there is one field for each day. The fields are D1 through D30. What I want to do is create a loop that deducts the requirements (D1 through D30) from the QOH until the QOH falls below zero. I am counting the number of days as it is looping y = y + 1 to come up with the number of days of coverage. I then will return the counted result into a field on the form

```
Private Sub PDS_AfterUpdate()

    Dim w As Integer 'generate the appropriate field reference'
    Dim y As Integer 'My counter (The Value) that I return to the form'
    Dim z As Double 'Quantity On Hand QOH'
    Dim a As String
    Dim strFieldName As String


    z = Me.P0 ' PO is the field that contains the QOH - Quantity On Hand

    If z < 0 Then ' If the QOH is already below zero return a -1
    y = -1
    End If

    If z >= 0 Then

    Do Until z < 0
    w = w + 1 'This is used to get the number to add to the field to get the correct field'
    a = "D" & w ' I then add the number to the field which starts with D to get the field that I want 
    to pull the value from'
    strFieldName = "me." & a
    z = z - strFieldName '<--- This is where I am stuck how do I get the value from the field I am 
    referencing in order to subtract it from the QOH'
    y = y + 1 'This is the counter that I return to the field in my form'

    Loop

    End If

    Me.DOH = y ' the field that the result is passed to on the form'

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Do Until z <= 0
    w = w + 1 
    a = "D" & CStr(w)
    z = z - Me(a).Value
    y = y + 1 
Loop
```